# Model that doesn't write pre-populate value to view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using the model class as below

```
public class Question
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public int QuestionNo { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public QuestionTypes QuestionType { get; set; }
    public List<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}
```

I created a text box in view as below.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.ID);
```

it pre-populate `ID` with the values provided which is not I want. I want text box should be empty when rendered and during `POST` value of the text box should be read by ID property. How can I achieve this or there is a problem with my design?

Comment: "it pre-populate ID with the values provided" - that's how model-binding is supposed to work. If you want an empty `<input />`, you need to use a nullable type and leave it null.

Comment: @TiesonT. question id cannot be null and this is the id which will map answer text with question.

Comment: I don't see a model property for "answer text" - is this the correct model?

Comment: your ID property is not `nullable`  so if you want to keep it null then you should add `?` nullable symbol for id proprety  ie `public long? ID { get; set; }`

Comment: @TiesonT. thank you for pointing out about answer text property. That is an issue I need to address.

Comment: @Imad You need to show an empty textbox to the users while they are populated and it is expected to get them populated during the data entry again?! The scenario is somehow ambigues

Comment: If I'm following what you're trying to do, I think you might want a hidden field to keep track of the question id.
@Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.ID);

Answer (score 0):

okay,,

if the Question object you're passing to the View is already initialized, then it will have some value in ID property and that will be shown in the view when you do databindings in the view

So before passing the Question object to the view , set the value of ID to null.

in this way , when your Question will go to view, it will have null value and the textboxfor will be empty

Comment: That was design problem. I Created a property, `AnswerText` and bound it to text box and that solved the problem.